# What is the proper HTTP response to send for requests that require SSL/TLS

Tags: http, rest, ssl, https, httpresponse

I'm designing an RESTful API where some calls are public over HTTP, and some require an API key and encryption over HTTPS.  I'm deliberating on what response code should be sent if an HTTP request is sent to one of the private resources.  So far the only one that jumps out at me is **412 - Precondition Failed**, but the standard indicates that the precondition is imposed by the requester not the server.

Is there an appropriate response code for this condition or do I just need to give in and do **400**?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The most secure way to force HTTP client to use HTTPS is [HTTP Strict Transport Security](http://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-ietf-websec-strict-transport-sec-14.txt).

Previously a common suggestion was to drop the connection, but this [practice has been removed in favor of HSTS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Transport_Layer_Protection_Cheat_Sheet#Rule_-_REMOVED_-_Do_Not_Perform_Redirects_from_Non-TLS_Page_to_TLS_Login_Page) (OWASP website).

Comment: 1. The HSTS draft has been [moved to the IETF](http://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-ietf-websec-strict-transport-sec). 2. reading it does not actually give a good answer to the OP's question.

Comment: HSTS enforces HTTPS on the <b>entire</b> site. The above poster wanted some resource to be available over HTTP while others only over HTTPS. So HSTS cannot be used since it applies for all resources.

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question.   He was asking about what to do when a client connects over http, not HSTS headers which only have effect when the user has already connected over https.

Comment: You can preload HSTS in the browser to prevent any http call, https://hstspreload.org/

Answer (score 30):

I cannot say if this is broadly accepted by HTTP clients, but speaking strictly RFC, the server should respond with:

```
HTTP/1.1 426 Upgrade Required
Upgrade: TLS/1.0, HTTP/1.1
Connection: Upgrade
```

Source:
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2817#section-4.2

Comment: Interesting. RFC and OWASP differ in their recommendations. I prefer OWASP's version - don't respond to the request and just drop the packet. With the RFC approach, a man-in-the-middle could intercept the response (since it isn't https yet) and redirect to a spoofed website.

Comment: Yes, I agree - it's definitely a vulnerability. Even if dropping the connection might be confusing, security concerns should take precedence here. Also, note that the mentioned RFC is now practically 10 years old (in those times security might not have been such an important aspect as it is today).

Comment: You know, after looking closer at this I realized this is for an upgrade to TLS, presumably from some earlier version of SSL.  I'm not doing TLS, so I can't use that header, and since the spec is specifically for TLS I don't think this is appropriate.  Unfortunately I also don't have a way to drop the connection...

Comment: `https` as we know widely know it is specified in RFC 2818 (HTTP over TLS). RFC 2817 is virtually never used. @dasil003, note that IETF specs call TLS "TLS" because it's an IETF standard (SSL is not): you could easily read all of them with "SSL" in mind (except that it would refer to earlier versions indeed). RFC 2817 is not about upgrading to TLS (1.x) from SSLv3, it's about upgrading to SSL/TLS from plain HTTP, on the same connection.

Comment: @SripathiKrishnan
Even if your server would drop the http request, man-in-the-middle/intercept attack is still possible. Practically, unless the client is using https, it cannot be guaranteed that whatever response they get is not mangled.

Comment: Definitely think the MITM discussion is overthinking it. MITM can intercept before you even have a packet to drop. If client attempts http, the deed is done. Purpose of 426 is to tell the client's developers to fix their darn code.

Answer (score 7):

The appropriate error code to return would be similar to [403.4 - SSL required](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403).

Although not explicitly documented in the [RFC for HTTP 1.1](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.4), this behavior does match the requirements outlined there:

> The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it. Authorization will not help and the request SHOULD NOT be repeated. If the request method was not HEAD and the server wishes to make public why the request has not been fulfilled, it SHOULD describe the reason for the refusal in the entity. If the server does not wish to make this information available to the client, the status code 404 (Not Found) can be used instead.

Adding your own subcode (as with the SSL example) might be helpful in some cases, but since this subcode would not be meaningful to third parties, I would recommend against it.

So, your final error message would be something like "403 - Private Resource". Note that, even in the case of a missing API key, "401 - Unauthorized" should not be used, unless your API key can actually be transmitted in a WWW-Authenticate header field.

Comment: Note that the IIS status codes are bogus. HTTP status codes are composed of numbers only (3 exactly). See http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html#sec6.1.1 Also note that the reason phrase for 403 is "Forbidden" and that this is not subject to modification. Any further explanation should go into the response *body*.

Comment: Yeah, as appealing as that subcode is I can't behind the non-standardized nature of it.

Comment: I agree with other commenters that a subcode should not be used, but a case could be made for a plain 403. For example, that's what Twitter is using for their API. See https://dev.twitter.com/docs/security/using-ssl

Answer (score 7):

Returning a **403** with reason phrase "**HTTPS Required**" seems like a practical option and what I use.

see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403

Redirecting a REST Api is not a good idea especially as you may have no idea as to how or what is consuming your service.

Answer (score 0):

Just send a redirect to the corresponding https: URI.

**UPDATE**

The is a wrong answer - see comments below

Comment: There's a security risk. "An attacker performing a man in the middle attack could intercept the HTTP redirect response and send the user to an alternate page" - from OWASP SSL Best Practices

Comment: That does not stop users from still referring to the http url, in fact, with most http clients they won't even see that an http redirect took place. Sweeping the problem under the rug is probably not the approach you want to take.

Comment: Yes, sorry. You guys are right. Sending a redirect is the wrong thing to do. Thanks for pointing that out.