# What HTTP code to return for wrong protocol

Tags: http, http-status-codes

I'm wanting to return a HTTP code for a user that hits HTTP on a HTTPS only domain or vice versa. Which [HTTP Code](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) would be suited for this?

I don't want to redirect to the correct protocol as it would promote bad/insecure links and my server setup doesn't allow me to disable the protocol on the domains.

I'm thinking 400, 403, 406, or 500.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554778/what-is-the-proper-http-response-to-send-for-requests-that-require-ssl has some suggestions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It think you are looking for: [403 Forbidden](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.4) (at least this one I would opt for)

> The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it.
>   Authorization will not help and the request SHOULD NOT be repeated. If
>   the request method was not HEAD and the server wishes to make public
>   why the request has not been fulfilled, it SHOULD describe the reason
>   for the refusal in the entity. If the server does not wish to make
>   this information available to the client, the status code 404 (Not
>   Found) can be used instead

Comment: +1. This makes sense. Incidentally, Microsoft agrees with your answer, and even chose to (incorrectly) "extend" the 403 status code to *[403.4 - SSL Required](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403)* for IIS.

Comment: @Cristi Would you use this for both HTTP on HTTPS-only and HTTPS on HTTP-only?

Comment: I think yes, because the server has a good reason why to not fulfill the request. Moreover it tells the client to not repeat...