# Return HTTP substatus error codes from NancyFX?

Tags: nancy

I'd like to return a "403.4: SSL required" [substatus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403) from Nancy. How can I do this? I'm using ASP.NET hosting.

Answer (score 2):

You can't unfortunately, Nancy is hosting agnostic, so only supports status codes, not the made up substatus codes that only IIS uses :-)

OWASP would suggest you just drop connections that don't use HTTPS, although IETF seem to suggest using 426 https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2817#section-4.2 ( from [What is the proper HTTP response to send for requests that require SSL/TLS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554778/what-is-the-proper-http-response-to-send-for-requests-that-require-ssl) )

Comment: You *can* but you would have to create your own host (easy, copy our code) and then stick the code in the NancyContext and read that into the substatus.